# How to access LAN behind VPN client from server?

Tags: networking, openvpn, iproute

I have a cloud VM running an OpenVPN server
On the other side, I have a Synology NAS inside a private network.

I would like to access the client's LAN (192.168.1.0/24) from the server.

On the server, I fixed its VPN IP, and `iroute` to the client:

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/ccd/hodor
ifconfig-push 192.168.2.142 255.255.255.0
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Also I configured in `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf` a route to the client:

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

So I am now able to ping the client (192.168.2.142 and 192.168.1.20) from the server:

```
server$ ping -c1 192.168.1.20
PING 192.168.1.20 (192.168.1.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=14.8 ms

server$ ping -c1 192.168.2.142
PING 192.168.2.142 (192.168.2.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=14.1 ms
```

From the client I can see the ARP request:

```
client$ tcpdump -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
20:37:17.666777 IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.1.20: ICMP echo request, id 14, seq 1, length 64
20:37:17.666813 IP 192.168.1.20 > 192.168.2.1: ICMP echo reply, id 14, seq 1, length 64
20:37:21.022983 IP 192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.142: ICMP echo request, id 15, seq 1, length 64
20:37:21.023026 IP 192.168.2.142 > 192.168.2.1: ICMP echo reply, id 15, seq 1, length 64
```

However, I cannot access/ping the other devices on the client's LAN interface, but I have plenty of them:

```
client$ sudo ip neigh
192.168.1.31 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr a8:a1:59:83:83:0c REACHABLE
192.168.1.3 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 3c:6a:9d:13:d1:86 STALE
192.168.1.2 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr ec:b5:fa:09:07:ac STALE
172.17.0.4 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:04 STALE
192.168.1.1 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 44:fe:3b:f9:05:1a REACHABLE
172.17.0.6 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:06 STALE
192.168.1.18 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 02:11:32:20:17:25 REACHABLE
172.17.0.2 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:02 STALE
192.168.1.11 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 60:fb:00:8f:cb:8e REACHABLE
172.17.0.3 dev docker0 lladdr 02:42:ac:11:00:03 REACHABLE
192.168.1.9 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 5c:ea:1d:74:fa:bb STALE
192.168.1.15 dev ovs_eth3 lladdr 9e:12:c6:2f:1a:0b STALE
```

Of course, I can access/ping my devices from the client side.

How can I configure my NAS to allow the VPN server to access the client's devices?

Comment: Is the client configured to forward ip traffic? Can you show the output of `ip route` on the server when the VPN connection is active? Are other systems on the client network configured to route responses to the server via the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure OpenVPN to redirect the traffic from other subnets.

First I recommend to enable the client's peer configuration by uncommenting this line in `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`:

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

Then you create a `/etc/openvpn/ccd/client-name` file containing this:

```
ifconfig-push 192.168.2.142 255.255.255.0
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

The `push` configuration informs the client to take the `192.168.2.142` IP address. This would be therefore static for this client.

Then the `iroute` command would allow `192.168.1.0/24` to pass through this VPN link.

From this, you should be able to run an ICMP command for whatever client on the server and assess it is received from the client side with `tcpdump`.

Normally, this won't allow you to reach that client, because Masquerading is not enabled on the client's LAN port. For this you should enable both IP forwarding and masquerade on the eth0 (ovs_eth0?) port:

ip -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE -o eth0

Then it should work.

Ensure to save that iptables configuration. You may configure this after your NAS boot with a script in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/iptables_nat.sh` for example.